Open a C API function within an DLL file from c# gives memory access error
The C API declaration looks like this
include <nsfdb.h>
STATUS LNPUBLIC NSFDbOpen(
    const char far *PathName,
    DBHANDLE far *rethDB
);

https://opensource.hcltechsw.com/domino-c-api-docs/reference/Func/NSFDbOpen/
[DllImport("nnotes.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int NSFDbOpen(string path, ref IntPtr pHandleDb);

I have tried Cdecl and stdcall. I have tried ref / out IntPtr and int
When I do call the function
 int result = NSFDbOpen(dbPath, ref dbHandle);

I get this error

I can add that I've used this in Visual basic 6 and then the handle was a long
=====Update=====
in older code it looked like this
Declare Private Function WinNSFDbOpen Lib "nnotes" Alias "NSFDbOpen" ( Byval dbname As String, dbhandle As Long ) As Integer

And the function doing the call like this
Function apiNSFDbOpen ( Byval dbname As String, dbhandle As Long ) As Integer       
    apiNSFDbOpen = winNSFDbOpen ( dbname, dbhandle ) 
End Function


char* is single-byte, not Unicode.
[DllImport("nnotes.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int NSFDbOpen(string path, ref IntPtr pHandleDb);


in older code it looked like this
Declare Private Function WinNSFDbOpen Lib "nnotes" Alias "NSFDbOpen" ( Byval dbname As String, dbhandle As Long ) As Integer
And the function doing the call like this
Function apiNSFDbOpen ( Byval dbname As String, dbhandle As Long ) As Integer
apiNSFDbOpen = winNSFDbOpen ( dbname, dbhandle )
End Function

VB6 defaults to Ansi unless you tell it Declare Unicode Function

OK so how should I change the code above to make it more correct?

I just showed you what to do: add CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
